# How to split current date time and retrieve only date , hour and minute?

Tags: python

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print("current time ", current_time)
```

Result:

```
current time  2021-03-08 23:22:59.912410
```

Here, I want only up to minutes(2021-03-08 23:22) and need to get rid of seconds and milliseconds from the current time.
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strftime()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) to output dates on a specific format, i.e.:

```
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print("current time ", current_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
# current time 2021-03-09 04:42:57
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/6903d649f6)

Comment: Beat me to it. @TechG, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) is the table for the symbols Pedro used (`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`) in the Python docs.

Answer (score -1):

You have to re-format the time in string as per the format you want.

```
formatted = current_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(formatted)
```

Output will be like:

```
'2021-03-09 10:12:58'
```

It also changes the `datetime` object to `str`. And hence  `datetime` operations can not be performed on it. It is recommended to use only for output presentation.